# How do I use a index.php with brunch?

Tags: brunch

I'm using the brunch build system, and want to use a .php index file instead of .html.  I get the following error when I watch the server.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/indigoshade/Desktop/test/simple/public/index.html'

How do I have brunch look for index.php instead of index.html?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side programming language so the code has to be interpreted before it can be shown on the web page. This is done on the server ("the backend"). Brunch is focused on Javascript, HTML, CSS etc ("the frontend").

To get started with locally developing PHP applications, I suggest following some tutorial. I am sure that you can find some on [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=local+development+environment+php) .

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm aware of that. I just wanted to use brunch on 95% java-script application that used php, I like the live-reload. I found a solution for live reload on any local application using the OSX app LiveReload.